# Is there an official/unoffiicial record kept of 'Three Line Whips' in UK Parliament?

Tags: united-kingdom

At the Westminster Parliament in UK, there is a mechanism called a Three Line Whip, by which a political party attempts to control the attendance/voting intentions of its MP's. It's unofficial, and I understand that no trace of it appears in 'Hansard', the record of Parliamentary business.

Does anyone know if there is an unofficial publicly accessible record anywhere that shows details of when three line whips have been in force... dates, which party...?

Answer (score 2):

There is not an official record.

In response to a request in 2013 for a list of free votes the then Leader of the Commons [responded](https://researchbriefings.parliament.uk/ResearchBriefing/Summary/SN04793):

> Whipping is a matter for individual parties and not a matter that the Government can comment on.

Neither Parliament nor the government keep an official record of which votes have been whipped. Moreover, as the weekly letter that MPs receive ("The Whip") is confidential, it is difficult for independent observers to make an accurate list. Moreover, even some "free votes" have some behind-the-scenes whipping.

The House of Commons library has published [a list of "free" votes](http://researchbriefings.files.parliament.uk/documents/SN04793/SN04793.pdf); in general other divisions have been whipped